# Boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 18

Tags: python

I try to learn code in Image Processing with Python but i have a error

```
bins_num = int(brick_lbp.max() + 1)
brick_hist = np.histogram(brick_lbp, normed=True, bins=bins_num, range=(0, bins_num))
lbp_features = [brick_rot_lbp, grass_rot_lbp, wall_rot_lbp]

min_score = 1000 # Set a very large best score value initially
idx = 0 # To keep track of the winner
for feature in lbp_features:
    histogram, _ = np.histogram(feature, normed=True, bins=bins_num, range=(0,bins_num))
    p = np.asarray(brick_hist)
    q = np.asarray(histogram)
    filter_idx = np.logical_and(p != 0, q != 0)
    score = np.sum(p[filter_idx] * np.diff(p[filter_idx] / q[filter_idx]))
    if score < min_score:
        min_score = score
        winner = idx
    idx = idx + 1
```

boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 18

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please correct your code sample format.

Comment: NameError: name 'brick_lbp' is not defined. Can you make this code reproducible? Please add all variables used in your sample. It would be good if you test this small code pieces if the throw the error you want a solution to and not an other. It helps all to help you.